# indexing pandas series with an integer value

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, series

I have two pandas series like following.

```
bulk_order_id
Out[283]: 
3    523
Name: order_id, dtype: object
```

and

```
luster_6_loc
Out[285]: 
3    Cluster 3
Name: Clusters, dtype: object
```

Now I want a new series which would look like this.

```
Cluster 3  523
```

I am doing following in python

```
cluster_final = pd.Series()
for i in range(len(cluster_6_loc)):
    cluster_final.append(pd.Series(bulk_order_id.values[i], index =  
    cluster_6_loc.iloc[i]))
```

Which gives me an error saying

```
TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'Cluster 3' was passed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe better is use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
print bulk_order_id

1    523
2    528
3    527
4    573
Name: order_id, dtype: object

print cluster_6_loc

1    Cluster 1
2    Cluster 2
3    Cluster 3
4    Cluster 4
Name: Clusters, dtype: object

cluster_final = pd.concat([bulk_order_id, cluster_6_loc], axis=1).set_index('Clusters')
#reset index name
cluster_final.index.name = ''

print cluster_final.ix[:,0]

Cluster 1    523
Cluster 2    528
Cluster 3    527
Cluster 4    573
Name: order_id, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass to `pd.Series` values of `luster_6_loc` as index and values of `bulk_order_id` as values:

```
bulk_order_id = pd.Series(523, index=[3])
cluster_6_loc= pd.Series('Cluster 3', index=[3])

cluster_final = pd.Series(bulk_order_id.values, cluster_6_loc.values)

In [149]: cluster_final 
Out[149]:
Cluster 3    523
dtype: int64
```

**EDIT**

It's strange but it seems that `append` to `Series` doesn't work correctly (at least in version `0.17.1`):

```
s = pd.Series()

In [199]: s.append(pd.Series(1, index=[0]))
Out[199]:
0    1
dtype: int64

In [200]: s
Out[200]: Series([], dtype: float64)
```

Btw for your case your could do `set_value`:

```
cluster_final = pd.Series()
for i in range(len(cluster_6_loc)):
    cluster_final.set_value(cluster_6_loc.iloc[i], bulk_order_id.values[i])

In [209]: cluster_final
Out[209]:
Cluster 3    523
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Ok. It works. But, it doesn't work when I iterate through a for loop.

Comment: @user2927983 why are need to iterate through a for loop? Could you use just values from both series?

Comment: I can have more than one value in both the series. that's the reason I want to iterate through for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether I'm understanding your question correctly, but what's wrong with `pd.concat()` ([see docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)):

```
s1 = pd.Series(data=['523'], index=[3])

3    523
dtype: object

s2 = pd.Series(data=['Cluster 3'], index=[3])

3    Cluster 3
dtype: object
```

and using `pd.concat()`, which would also work for several values:

```
pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1)

     0          1
3  523  Cluster 3
```

resulting in a `DataFrame` which is what you'll probably need anyway when combining `Series` with several values. You can move any of the `values` to the `index` using `.set_index()`, or add `.squeeze()` to get a `Series` instead.

So `pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1).set_index(1)` gives:

```
             0
1             
Cluster 3  523
```

Comment: It gives me a empty series. `Out[298]: Series([], dtype: float64)`

Comment: You had asked about the `TypeError`. I updated my answer to reflect your new question about multiple values per `Series`.